# Running two Countdown Timers Sequentially

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, countdown

I'm a Kotlin newbee. I am trying to program a countdown timer for an archery countdown clock. First the countdown timer countDownP runs for 10 sec, then runs countdown timer countDown for 60 sec. However the two timers won't run sequentially unless I nest the 2nd timer inside the onFinish() of the 1st timer.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Here's the code

```
import ...

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //initialize clock countdown timers for prep and shoot
    internal lateinit var countDownP: CountDownTimer
    internal lateinit var countDown: CountDownTimer
    internal var isClockRun = false

    // set-up initial clock values
    internal val endTime: Long = 60000
    internal val prepTime: Long = 10000
    internal val warn1Time: Long = 45000
    internal val totEnds: Int = 10
    internal val totPEnds: Int = 3
    internal var totLine: Int = 6
    internal var totTurn: Int = 3

    // set-up initial clock variables
    internal var endNo: Int = 1
    internal var endPNo: Int = 1
    internal var turnNo: Int = 1
    internal var isEndP = true
    internal var sUntilFinished: Long = 0

//******* PROGRAM CODE STARTS ***********
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //set-up various views on screen
        // set-up initial view on starting

// **START BUTTON**
        startButton.setOnClickListener {
            countDownP = object : CountDownTimer(prepTime, 500) {
                init {
                }

                override fun onTick(msUntilFinished: Long) {
                    sUntilFinished = msUntilFinished / 1000
                    
                    resultTextViewTimer.text = "${(sUntilFinished / 60)}:${(sUntilFinished % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')}"
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                    // when prep countdownP finished, start main countdown
                    isClockRun = false
                    isEndP = false
                }
            }
            countDown = object : CountDownTimer(endTime, 500) {
                init {
                    isClockRun = true
                }

                override fun onTick(msUntilFinished: Long) {
                    sUntilFinished = msUntilFinished / 1000
                    if (msUntilFinished <= warn1Time) {
                    }

                    resultTextViewTimer.text = "${(sUntilFinished / 60)}:${(sUntilFinished % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')}"
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                    isClockRun = false
                }
            }
            if (!isClockRun) {
                if (isEndP) {
                    isClockRun = true
                    countDownP.start()
                } else {
                    isClockRun = true
                    countDown.start()
                }
            }
        }
// **STOP BUTTON**
        stopButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (isClockRun) {
                isClockRun = false
                if (isEndP) countDownP.cancel()
                if (!isEndP) countDown.cancel()
                isEndP = true
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a timer for 70 seconds and do the work of `countDownP` for 10 seconds and then do the work of `countDown` for 60 seconds.

In this way, I think it will be more efficient.

Comment: I need to run the countdown from 10-0, then reset the timer to 60 and countdown from 60-0. I can't just run it from 70-0.

Comment: This also you can do with one-timer, why I am saying this is because if you compare the extra logic that you have to write vs the resource that a timer will consume. I will prefer to write some extra logic. Rest is your choice.